# Magento 2.3 migration issue, configurable products causing 503 error

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.3, magento2-migration-tool, data-migration, frontend-error

I'm facing those issues after data migration from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.3 :

- configurable products are causing 503 server error on front-end.
- categories with configurable products are causing 503 server error.
- searching for a configurable product is causing 503 server error.
- PHP LOGS

  ```
  [21-Mar-2019 03:16:01] WARNING: [pool example.com] child 57516 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 1.659686 seconds from start
  [21-Mar-2019 03:16:01] NOTICE: [pool example.com] child 57576 started
  ```
- DOMAIN LOGS:

  AH01067: Failed to read FastCGI header, referer: https://example.com/
  (104)Connection reset by peer: AH01075: Error dispatching request to: , referer: https://example.com/
- Magento 2.3 fresh install and default theme
- The products have unique URL's
- I managed to have them all working by opening and saving one single random product. Reindexing will make them crash again.

• Magento LOGS :

```
main.ERROR: Warning: SessionHandler::read(): open(/var/lib/php/sessions/sess_ub6spo4jcfmsh0itec4jahoik8, O_RDWR) failed: Permission denied (13) in /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22


main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp
```

Environment :
Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS‬
Plesk Onyx - Version 17.8.11 Update #45
PHP 7.2.16 - FPM Application Served by Apache
Nginx : Proxy mode + Smart static files processing

PHP Settings :
max_input_vars = 10000
max_input_nesting_level = 800
precision = 14
output_buffering = 44096
memory_limit : 10GO
max_execution_time : 180000
max_input_time : 180000